# RESTEasy / JAX-RS spec versions?

Tags: java, jax-rs, resteasy

I know that RESTEasy 3.x uses JAX-RS 2.0. Which versions of RESTEasy correspond to JAX-RS 1.0, 1.1 and 1.1.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Bill's blog](https://bill.burkecentral.com/category/resteasy/) (Bill Burke is one of the main RESTEasy creators):

- RESTEasy 3.x is JAXRS 2.0,
- RESTEasy 2.x is JAXRS 1.1,
- RESTEasy 1.x is JAXRS 1.0.

There is no JAXRS 1.1.1 specification as per [JSR 311](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=311), though surprisingly you can find JAXRS 1.1.1 API with updates to JAXRS 1.1. API.

Comment: The RESTEasy creator blog is a good reference for such information. Hence, +1

Comment: Updated as per your comments

Answer (score 2):

While Jersey uses [`javax.ws.rs`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs) artifacts as dependency (so you can know the JAX-RS version by the dependencies), RESTEasy repacks JAX-RS classes into their own JARs.

Both RESTEasy 1.x and 2.x implement the JAX-RS 1.x specification. The JAX-RS 2.x specification is only mentioned in RESTEasy 3.x documentation.

Documentation:

- [RESTEasy 1.0.0.GA](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.0.0.GA/userguide/html_single/)
- [RESTEasy 2.0.0.GA](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.0.0.GA/userguide/html_single/index.html)
- [RESTEasy 3.0.0.Final](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.0.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html)